# Self scheduled Python script

Tags: python, scripting, scheduled-tasks

I'm writing an Python script that calls a function that exports and imports spaces from the wiki tool Confluence. It has to run everyday, but we can't use cron so i'm looking for a way to schedule it by her self.

I've created the following. I can already schedule it for the next day but not for the following day again..

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from __future__ import print_function
from sys import argv
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Timer
import sys,os,subprocess
import getpass
from subprocess import PIPE,Popen

date = (os.popen("date +\"%d-%m-%y - %T\""))
x=datetime.today()
y=x.replace(day=x.day+1, hour=13, minute=56, second=0, microsecond=0)
delta_t=y-x
secs=delta_t.seconds+1


def runExport():
   # HERE IS ALL THE CODE THAT HAS TO RUN EVERYDAY

t = Timer(secs, runExport)
t.start()
```

Could somebody please help me out? The script has to run everyday for example an 05.00 am.

Version of python is 2.6.6. And sadly enough no option to import a module..

Thank you!

Comment: Out of interest, why can't you use cron? If cron can't be trusted, why would a replacement be trusted?

Comment: I think the problem is more of starting the script when it the server is rebooted. What is the server's os?

Comment: It's a policy of the company.. Sadly enough we have to do it this way what probably also will be killed if they know it..

Comment: You may get mileage out of the https://github.com/dbader/schedule module

Comment: My fault.. Reboot doesn't matter. Than we start it manual!

Comment: so a cron `@reboot` job to start it would be frowned on? ;)  You could also set it up as a service with a file in `/etc/init.d/` `/etc/init` or whichever variation on startup environment your OS uses

Comment: I don't have any root permissions on the server. It's has to be done with a application user on thet server.

Comment: How bizarre, I wonder why they have a policy against cron, especially when it makes so much extra work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using something a bit simplilar then what you are doing there. There is a simple scheduling library in python called sched, which can be found here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html

A simple example of using this for your implement:

```
import sched, time
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
delay_seconds = 5
def print_time():
    print time.time()
    s.enter(delay_seconds,1,print_time,argument=())

s.enter(delay_seconds,1,print_time,argument=())
s.run()
```

This code will run every 5 seconds, and print out the current time. just change delay_seconds to the delay you want your interval to run, and your done.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but can't you simply use the Windows Task Scheduler for this?

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11949-elevated-program-shortcut-without-uac-prompt-create.html